# TypeScript import from file that isn't default

Tags: typescript, apollo, apollo-server

I'm trying to import a type definition from a file in a external dependency that isn't the default file `index.d.ts`, but instead from another file.

Normally, when importing from an external npm module, you need to use the syntax:

```
import { Foo } from "bar";
```

In that case it will try to find some "common" files from `node_modules/bar/`, for example `index.d.ts`, ...

Instead I need to import the type `ITypedef` from file `Interfaces` defined in npm module `graphql-tools`.

I tried to do:

```
import { ITypedef } from "graphql-tools/Interfaces"
```

However it didn't work.

How can I do that kind of imports?

Thanks

Comment: What was the error when you have tried like this

Comment: It gives the following error: `Cannot find module 'graphql-tools/Interfaces'.`